# Dependent Drop-Down Lists with functions indirect or index+match functions still gets me a #VALUE! or #REF! error

Tags: indexing, drop-down-menu, excel-indirect

I followed 2 tutorials respectively
-[indirect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjIzdnRndgE) dependent drop down lists
-[index and match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7cHgsFirLk) dependent drop down lists

For the indirect function `=INDIRECT(C6)` as soon as I use some names with spaces e.g. 'selfish yes' they will end up with underscores when I create the name from a selection ctrl+shift+F3 as you can see in the 'Name Manager' I have now selfish_yes). If I use indirect on 'selfish yes' I get a #REF! error. As soon as there are no spaces such as 'generous' I have a #VALUE! error.

[DependantDropDownList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4nGl.png)

But if I double now double click on cell D18 so I have the code highlighted '=INDIRECT(D18)' and I then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER I get the first value of my 2nd dropdown list which is 'grrrr' but I can't select the following 'NotWorking' or 'NotHappy'.

[Result after Ctrl+Shift+Enter on cell E18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz6hE.png)

I can change D18 from angry to happy and see again the first element from my list 'yesss' appear. But as soon as I double click again on E18 and press Enter I get the #Value! error again

For the index and match function

I used e.g. for cell D9 `=INDEX(D2:E3,,MATCH($C$9,$D$1:$E$1,0))` as per the tutorial and I get #Value! Error independant with space or not. I tried an example with no spaces anywhere with 'angry' and 'happy' and still get the same.

I really used the same way as per the 2 tutorials and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I checked also the separator under clock and Region which for me has no influence on this case I think.
[ClockAndRegion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAtqr.png)

What I want to achieve is simple and I can't get my hand on what goes wrong. Ideally I want my dependant double drop down list to have numbers and '.' for example

1.Technical Risk [1st list with the 2nd list being 1.1-2-3...]
1.1 Definition of Perimeter
1.2 Definition of requirements
1.3 ...

2. Risk Management
   2.1 Project Management
   2.2 ...

If I select 1. in my first cell I want the next cell to offer 1.1, 1.2, ... which is what the 2 tutorials show...

Thanks if someone finds what's blocking it'd be really appreciated I'd really want to break down this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with a friend, I was simply not putting the formula inside the source of the data validation of my list {=INDEX($U$12:$X$18,,MATCH(G8,$U$11:$X$11,0))}. When this code was pasted inside everything was ok.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8qVX.png)